# Official VSCode in browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The new July update of VSCode looks very interesting, particulary the Browser Support ( https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_48#_browser-support ) where a developer seems to have opened VSCode inside a browser using localhost:9888.

Does anyone know how to do that? I can't seem to find any documentation about this and the only results I get are for code-server, which is not a official VSCode project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_engineering

According to the description, in your local fork of the vscode repository, running `yarn web` from the command line.